# Iterations through rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit confused on how to use both while and for loop.
What I would like to achieve is the following:

- set a threshold to stop the process
- if the initial value is below this threshold, then for each number, sum the values within the same rows
- update the counter for the value
- check the updated value: if it is still below the threshold, then continue to sum until the threshold value is reached.

I set a `threshold = 2` and initialize the counter `n` to `0`. I tried this logic:

```
    while n <= threshold:  # need to keep the while loop
      for x in df['Value']:  # need to keep the for loop
        # create new columns by sum      
        n=n+1 # increase the counter by 1
```

For instance: I have

```
Value
1
2
3
```

Since `n=0` is smaller than the threshold (`2`), I create a new column with the sum:

```
Value Sum
1      1
2      2
3      3
```

I go with n=1, so I will have

```
Value Sum  Sum1
1      1     2
2      2     4
3      3     6
```

and so on (in this example, until n=2).
My desired output would be

```
Value Sum  Sum1 Sum2
1      1     2   4
2      2     4   8
3      3     6   12
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't stop when the threshold is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, A simple `for loop` along with `sum` would suffice

```
for i in range(threshold+1):
    df[f'Sum{i}'] = df.sum(1)
```

Alternatively you can try a more efficient `Numpy Approach`

```
a = df['Value'].values[:, None] * 2 ** np.r_[:threshold + 1]
df.join(pd.DataFrame(a).add_prefix('Sum'))
```

---

```
   Value  Sum0  Sum2  Sum3
0      1     1     2     4
1      2     2     4     8
2      3     3     6    12
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham. I would like to know, however, what it was not working in my code. It is still not clear why the code doesn't stop with the iteration once reached the threshold

Comment: @LdM Glad i could help! Can you please edit your question to add some more code so that i can see the problem?

Comment: @LdM The statement `df["Sum"] = df.iloc[:,- c_previous:].sum(axis=1) ` seems incorrect apart from this; the statement where you are increasing the value of counter should be out of for loop but inside a while loop further I don't see where in the code you are updating the value of `c_previous`. I would advise you not to use the loop based approach because iterating overs the rows of dataframe is really a bad idea. Makes sense?

Comment: Thank you so much, Shubham. It absolutely makes sense :)

Comment: @LdM Happy coding!